# Is there a way to diagnose why git init --bare doesn't create specific directories?

Tags: git, gitolite

I'm attempting to run Gitolite on my LEDE-Project router.  I've followed the instructions [provided here](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/gitolite) to satisfactorily install the necessary dependencies onto my router.  My router reports Git version 
2.11.0, as does the computer I'm running this on.  The package for Git on LEDE-Project and OpenWRT [can be found here](https://github.com/openwrt/packages/blob/master/net/git/Makefile), as they're sharing those repos.

When I create a new repository in the Gitolite way, I get an error message similar to this:

> 2017-03-06.03:11:23  28046   die could not symlink /root/.gitolite/hooks/common/update to gitolite-admin.git/hooks<> at
>    /root/gitolite/src/lib/Gitolite/Conf/Store.pm line 368.<>

After a good nights' sleep, I eventually worked the cause of this down to [this specific mailing list post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gitolite/2KXZ5grk1Bk/tiPi-G7_OtkJ), which suggested that `git init --bare` was not producing the right directories.

> Try "git init --bare" in an empty directory and tell me if you see a 
>   .git/hooks directory in it.
>
> Assuming you don't, you'll have to fix that somehow.  Gitolite expects a 
>   'git init --bare' to create a hooks directory.

Seems like a reasonable assumption.  My machine does this just fine.

```
git init --bare foo
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/makoto/workspace/foo/foo/
cd ~/foo
ls -la
drwxrwxr-x 7 makoto makoto 4096 Mar  6 13:15 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 makoto makoto 4096 Mar  6 13:15 ..
drwxrwxr-x 2 makoto makoto 4096 Mar  6 13:15 branches
-rw-rw-r-- 1 makoto makoto   66 Mar  6 13:15 config
-rw-rw-r-- 1 makoto makoto   73 Mar  6 13:15 description
-rw-rw-r-- 1 makoto makoto   23 Mar  6 13:15 HEAD
drwxrwxr-x 2 makoto makoto 4096 Mar  6 13:15 hooks
drwxrwxr-x 2 makoto makoto 4096 Mar  6 13:15 info
drwxrwxr-x 4 makoto makoto 4096 Mar  6 13:15 objects
drwxrwxr-x 4 makoto makoto 4096 Mar  6 13:15 refs
```

On my router...not so much.

```
git init --bare foo
Initialized empty Git repository in /root/foo/
cd foo/
ls -la
drwxr-xr-x    4 root     root          4096 Mar  6 13:21 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Mar  6 13:21 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            23 Mar  6 13:21 HEAD
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            66 Mar  6 13:21 config
drwxr-xr-x    4 root     root          4096 Mar  6 13:21 objects
drwxr-xr-x    4 root     root          4096 Mar  6 13:21 refs
```

The issue as far as Gitolite is concerned is that specifically the `hooks/` folder doesn't exist.  I can't figure out *why* this is, though.

Is there a way for me to diagnose what folders are created when `git init --bare` is run?  I get the feeling that I can figure the rest out if I can figure out what's actually being executed when the command is run.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is as if, on your server, the [template used for creating a new repo](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init#_template_directory) has an incomplete content (ie one without hooks)

That template folder would be in `<git>/share/git-core/templates`, with `<git>` being the installation folder (on Windows `./mingw64/share/git-core/templates`, on Linux, `/usr/share/git-core/templates`)

The lack of hooks can be intentional on a server which does not want any hook executed on it for security reason. (For instance, you cannot add hooks to a GitHub bare repo)

Comment: Interestingly enough, the templates folder is *empty*.  This has given me enough of a hint to go off of.  I'm going to investigate this portion of it when I get moment to.

Comment: Yep - it was definitely the fact that the templates were empty.  Placing an empty `hooks/` folder solved my issue.  Thank you!